# How to filter score to show summary for latest date?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm pulling information from csv files on a semi-regular almost daily basis and after normalization in Dataprep pushing it to a new table in Bigquery. In the scorecard we would like to show the composite data of only the latest date. e.g if it has data for 24th, 25th and 26th June then it should show the summary only for 26th June

I've tried using the MAX(EventDate) function to create a custom field as well as use it as a Date Range Dimension but neither approach seems to be working.

If any one has a solution to be able to identify the latest date and show information only for that would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you create the table you use via a query in BigQuery or is it the raw data (the table in Bigquery from Dataprep) that you are using?

Comment: It's the raw data that we are using.

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Data Studio are tricky and I don't think there's currently a way to achieve what you're trying to do as described.

However, there are ways around it. For example, you could create a table sorted by date descending and then use white (or whatever the colour of your dashboard is) shapes to hide everything except the top row's data.

You might have to play about with the table format and shapes to get it right so it's not ideal but it should do what you need it to until the function to create a scorecard is available.